# Masking an Object

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, swfobject

I am currently try to make an object in an attempt to make it unclickable. I am using a z-index but the problem is the object always places itself first. Is there a way to mask the object to its in the background?

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:1000px; height:100px; z-index:1001; background:#00F;opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40); left:0px; top:0px;"></div>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
    width="99%" height="99%" id="pdf" style="position:absolute; z-index:999;">
    <param name="movie" value="filename.pdf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="##FFFFFF">
    <embed src="filename.pdf" quality="high" bgcolor="##FFFFFF" width="99%" height="99%"
            name="2003map" align="" type="pdf">
    </embed>
</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try putting the z index as negative ? 
also try putting the object inside a div with z index that is lower than the other

like this

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:1000px; height:100px;
 z-index:1001;background:#00F;opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);
 left:0px; top:0px;">
</div>
<div style="z-index:999;" id="object_cantainer">
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
  width="99%" height="99%" id="pdf" style="position:absolute; ">
  <param name="Enabled" value="0" />
  <param name="movie" value="filename.pdf">
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="##FFFFFF">
  <embed src="filename.pdf" quality="high" bgcolor="##FFFFFF" width="99%" height="99%"
        name="2003map" align="" type="pdf">
  </embed>
 </object>
</div>
```

another option maybe setting the object onclick event to empty ?

Comment: Actually as a negative value, the PDF no longer loads.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925837/html-wrapper-div-over-embedded-flash-object-cannot-be-clickable-by-jquery

Comment: maybe setting this to 0 <param name="Enabled" value="1" />

Comment: It doesn't work. The div infront is only the top part. So the bottom part of the PDF should still show...in which it doesn't. Also the div has an opacity so the user can see whats behind.

Answer (score 0):

Also try using `wmode="opaque"`