# How to check if a request to a specific external web page was made

Tags: php, javascript, statistics, ads

I'm creating a plugin for my site that logs my ad clicks.

One method that I have just thought about is to check if a request to a specific page was made. This is because once the ads start playing they always request data from a specific external web page.

Is it possible for me to do this?
If it is please point me in the right direction.

a typical request looks something link this
http://neatlink.net/t/blank/blahblah-blah-blah

All of the requests are get requests.

Comment: you want to know when the ad was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a script tag that will attach an iframe to the webpage. Then to the page inside the iframe use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a click event to the ad and once it is clicked, make an ajax request to your script that logs the click.

See [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: These are flash video ads. Do you still think your suggestion is valid ?

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701760/jquery-click-listener-on-object-in-ie-failing , flash will 'swallow' the click event, but you can try wrapping it in div and bind a click on the div.

Comment: Ok that sound reasonable. But does that mean the div would have to be placed on top of the player ?

Comment: just wrapping the player object: <div> <object> </div>

Comment: Ok I think I've actually tried that. I added an this to the div onclick="alert('You just clicked this video')" but the alert never showed up... How am I supposed to know if it works before I start writing some more advanced code ?

Comment: Well, if you tried it and it didn't work then i guess it doesn't work... you should edit your question and mention the ad is a flash script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax object .There you can check if callback is called for readyState = 4 then it is ensured that a specific call is made.