# Stopping the video if the rotate is moving

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom, rotation

Ok so i have this [page](http://www.reelworks.net/wordpress/#). As you can see on this page I have a header that if you click on the three little dots on the right a new image and movie is displayed. this works great at the moment. The problem is the client now wants the page to rotate and I have tried this in the past but the problem arises when someone clicks on the movie and starts watching it. The page will continue to rotate and there is no way i could find to stop the rotate when the movie is clicked. I tried to wrap the video around a div tag and see if i can catch the click there with javascript but nothing..it still rotated....any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheap and dirty solution may be to not embed the Flash player right away, but instead show a preview still of the movie that looks like the player. When it's clicked, you can kill the page rotation, and load the Flash embed code on-the-fly.

If that doesn't float your boat, try reading up on the parts of the ActionScript API  that lets [Flash call Javascript](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the validated answer it sums things up: [javascript onclick event over flash object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object)