# flash element inside href

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, flash

Using the following code:

```
<a href="/someurl">
  <div class='mydiv' 
   onMouseOver="document.getElementById('myid').sendEvent('play');"
   onMouseOut="document.getElementById('myid').sendEvent('stop');">
    <div id='myid'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      flashplayer.init('myid');
    </script>
  </div>
</a>
```

Triggering play() and stop() works as expected, however the href doesn't do much, as the click event is sent to the flashplayer, and not following the hyperlink.

I have several such flashplayers on the page, and I'm trying to find a way to 'activate' the href onClick and honor the url specified in the `<a href="">` construct. Specifically, it's in IE8 I'm struggling.

How can I do this using html/javascript?

***Edit**:

After having come across [javascript onclick event over flash object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object) I managed to get closer to what I'm after. Using the onmousedown event, I can trigger javascript when clicking my overlay div. What's a good generic way to read the parent href url and issue `location.href='/myparenturl';" style="cursor: pointer;` ?

Comment: Why don't you use javascript for the href and place a onclick event?

Comment: Because the onclick event is captured by the flash, and not my overlaying div

Comment: Are you sure? Have actualy tried it?
if you do:
...
<div class='mydiv' 
onClick="alert('test')"
...
don't you get the alert?

Comment: I do not, I get the flash event, which is to pause the video (note, in IE8)

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I found this:
http://progproblems.blogspot.com/2009/08/javascript-onclick-for-flash-embeded.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's a good generic way to read the parent href url and issue
>   location.href='/myparenturl';" style="cursor: pointer; ?

Why watching for onmousedown on the div? I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tv8TQ/) demonstrating the extraction of the link attribute of each anchor tag on the page, just replace the `alert(link)` with `window.location(link)`. You could also use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsByTagName` if there are just *some* links you want to fix.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i = 0; i <= anchors.length; i++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i],
        link = anchor.getAttribute('href'),
        div = anchor.childNodes[0];
    div.onmousedown = function() {
        alert(link);
    }
}
```

update: inserted codesnippet

Comment: Because flash is stealing the onClick event