# How can I detect a rightmouse button event on mousedown?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, right-click

I am updating/debugging and expanding the capabilities of my draggable script and I need to be able to achieve the following result:

```
whatever.onRightMouseButtonMousedown = preventDefault();
```

I have done a lot of research to no avail, however, I know that it is possible to do this because when I use jquery-ui draggable, it prevents the ability to drag elements when you mousedown with the right mouse button.  I want to mimic this ability, and learn how it works so that I can implement it now and in the future as needed.

*Note: Please do not give me information about how to use jquery or jquery-ui draggable (I already am familiar with it), I want to learn how they implemented, or how it is possible to implement the detection of a mousedown with the right mouse button so that I can prevent elements from being draged with the right mouse button.*

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question is specifically asking how to do it without using jQuery.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Normally when you have any kind of mouse event, you'll want to have it only operate on one type of mouse click.  Therefore, the events passed to your callbacks have a property which allow you to distinguish between types of clicks.

This data is passed back through the **button** property of the event data.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.button) for finding out what values represent what data.

Therefore, you don't disable the right click, you instead only enable your functionality for the left click.  Here's a [poor] example:

```
element.onmousedown = function(eventData) {
  if (eventData.button === 0) {
      alert("From JS: the (left?) button is down!")
  }
}
```

the equivalent in jQuery is:

```
$("div").mousedown(function(eventData) {
    if (eventData.which === 0) {
        alert("From JQuery: which=" + eventData.which)
    }
});
```

Note that if you don't use jquery, the values returned will be different across browsers.  jQuery [unifies the values across browsers](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/), using 1 for left, 2 for middle, 3 for right:

```js
 element.onmousedown = function(eventData) {
   if (eventData.button === 0) {
     console.log("From JS: the (left?) button is down!")
   }
 }

 $("#element").ready(function() {
   $("div").mousedown(function(de) {
     console.log("From JQuery: which=" + de.which);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually already figured this out before coming back to check your comment, I would simply add that to make it work across browsers (at least modern browsers anyway) you just need to check for `event.which` and `event.button`, this is how I ended up resolving it:
`if (evt.which === 3 || evt.button === 2) {evt.preventDefault();`

Comment: FYI, for the left mouse button `event.button === 0`, for the mousewheel  `event.button === 1`, and for the right mouse button `event.button === 2` as explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button#Return_value

Answer (score 11):

The HTML, Javascript and demo:

```js
function mouseDown(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  switch (e.which) {
    case 1: alert('left'); break;
    case 2: alert('middle'); break;
    case 3: alert('right'); break; 
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onmousedown="mouseDown(event);">aaa</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not very simple.  Quirksmode.org has an [article about event properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html).

Look under 'Which mouse button has been clicked?' / 'Right click'.  It varies by browser.

Comment: I know this is from a while ago, but I clicked that link and saw the line "Not even explorer 6 supports it yet" meaning this article is ANCIENT.

Answer (score 0):

**I**t is also possible to have several mouse buttons pressed at the same time.

To know which mouse buttons are pressed,
you have to use Boolean algebra operators !

proceed as follows:

```js
const
  divX   = document.querySelector('#divX')
, Buttons_status = 
    { left       : { key : 0b00001, isDown: false }  // Primary button   (usually the left button)
    , right      : { key : 0b00010, isDown: false }  // Secondary button (usually the right button)
    , center     : { key : 0b00100, isDown: false }  // Auxiliary button (usually the mouse wheel button or middle button) 
    , bt_Back    : { key : 0b01000, isDown: false }  // 4th button (typically the "Browser Back" button)
    , bt_Forward : { key : 0b10000, isDown: false }  // 5th button (typically the "Browser Forward" button) 
    }

function testingButtons(e)
  {
  let DownBtns = ''
  for (let bt in Buttons_status )
    {
    Buttons_status[bt].isDown = !!(Buttons_status[bt].key & e.buttons )

    if (Buttons_status[bt].isDown) DownBtns += ' ' + bt
    }
  console.log ('Down buttton(s) :', DownBtns ? DownBtns : 'none' ) 
  // console.log( Buttons_status )
  }
 
divX.onmousedown = testingButtons
divX.onmouseup   = testingButtons

document.body.oncontextmenu =_=> false  // for clear testing
```

```css
#divX {
  display    : inline-block;
  background : lawngreen;
  margin     : .7em;
  padding    : 1em .7em;
  }
button {
  display        : inline-block;
  vertical-align : top;
  }
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 1.6em !important; 
  }
```

```html
<div id="divX"> 
  Do a mouse click anywhere here.
  <br><br>
  You can activate several buttons
  <br>
  <small>[do not release the previous button(s) when you press a new one]</small>
  <br><br>
  <small>(then realease just one of them)</small>
</div>

<button onclick="console.clear()">Clear</button>
```