# Check if mouse button is down on a button/picture and keep executing a function after every few seconds till the button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically what I am trying to do is, I am trying to call a **function** and repeat the same function after every "**n**" seconds till the mouse button is pressed (**MouseDown**) on a button/picture and stop calling the function when the mouse button is released (**MouseUp**). I am trying to do this using **JavaScript**!

**SOME REFERENCES**

> https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
>
> [How can I detect a rightmouse button event on mousedown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521519/how-can-i-detect-a-rightmouse-button-event-on-mousedown)
>
> [JavaScript: Check if mouse button down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322378/javascript-check-if-mouse-button-down?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `I am trying to call a function` just after the user clicks on the mouse or not?

Comment: Yes, and also repeat the same function after every "n" seconds till the button is pressed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var timerId = 0;

function onmousedown(ev) {
    console.log("Do something");  //first call right after mouse down
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("Do something");
    }, 2000);
}
function onmouseup(ev) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
}

var obj = document.getElementById("foo");
obj.addEventListener("mousedown", onmousedown);
obj.addEventListener("mouseup", onmouseup);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLnjh9zd/

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but to give an idea.

```
var state = false;

function repeatingFunction(){
    if (!state){
        return;
    }
    console.log("Do something");
    setTimeout(repeatingFunction, 2000);
}
function mymousedown(ev){
    state = true;
    repeatingFunction();
}
function mymouseup(ev){
    state = false;
}
var obj = document.getElementById("foo");
obj.addEventListener("mousedown", mymousedown);
obj.addEventListener("mouseup", mymouseup);
```

Comment: I have tried but its not working. Check if  I have made any error: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lke4t8y/

Comment: yes, little error. should be document.getElement.. not window.