# How to prevent right mouse button click onMouseDown() react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am using `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` for better control.
I already have `onContextMenu` but how I can prevent the right button click on `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp`.I only want the left button to be clicked.

because currently 2 events triggering at the same time. My context menu and other function open at the same time.

Comment: I don't believe you can prevent the event entirely, however you can detect which button is pressed and run/not run where appropriate: [How can I detect a rightmouse button event on mousedown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521519/how-can-i-detect-a-rightmouse-button-event-on-mousedown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onMouseDown={(event) => {
 if (event.button === 0) { ***write some code***}
}}
```

event.button === 0  `left`,
event.button === 1 `middle`,
event.button === 2  `right`,

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `e.button === 2` or not.
When you right click then the value of `e.button` is `2`.

Though i'm not sure about it's browser support.

You can check this example.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('left or right click');

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    if(e.button === 2) return;
    console.log('handleMouseDown');
  }
  
  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    if(e.button === 2) return;
    console.log('handleMouseUp');
  }
  
  const handleContextMenu = (e) => {
    console.log('handleContextMenu');
  }

  return (
    <div className="test" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp} onContextMenu={handleContextMenu} >{value}</div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```