# Embedded Facebook Video - Detect when user has played video

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, dom-events

I am embedding videos within my Facebook canvas app using the embed code provided by Facebook (and it plays fine):

```
<object width="1280" height="720">
     <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></param>
     <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEO_ID"></param>
     <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEO_ID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="1" width="1280" height="720"></embed>
</object>
```

What I'm wanting to do is to post an Open Graph Action (video.watches) 10 seconds after the user clicks play on the video.  However, I cannot find any documentation on how to interact with the video player or if there are any JavaScript events that can be used (like every video player I've worked with in the past).

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I'm using the technique described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4180324/8320

This at least gets me the ability to track an initial play event, but not pause, etc.