# How add link to object flash video?

Tags: javascript, flash, object, video, hyperlink

Good day.

I have code:

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal 
jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" 
jcarouselindex="1" style="float: left; list-style: none; width: 132px;">

<a href="test.php?link='.$i1['id'].'">

<object id="videoplayer3669" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
 data="./Uppod/uppod.swf" width="128" height="128">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="movie" value="./Uppod/uppod.swf">
<param name="flashvars" value="comment=test1&amp;st=./Uppod/video140_mini.txt&
amp;file=http://youtu.be/kSABXx6gcOs">
</object>
<a><div class="about">test1</div></a>

    <a>
                 </a></li>
```

I would like, that when i click on object video i follow on link `test.php?link='.$i1['id'].'`

[image: test]

But link in my code not worked...

Tell me please how make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, `<a>` usually doesn't work over `<object>`, so I use extra block after it with the same size and absolute positioning

EDIT [here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/VeZ6y/) - link is not precisely over the object, but you can correct it easily in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Three `<a>` are opening, but just two are closing. I think thats what you are looking for:

```
   <a href="test.php?link='.$i1['id'].'">
      <object> ....</object>
      <div class="about">test1</div>
    </a>
```

And if you want to output php variables into your html, you have to use `<?php echo $var ?>`

edit: check that SO answer by Darwin [javascript onclick event over flash object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object/4180324#4180324)

Comment: check the SO answer by @Darwin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object/4180324#4180324