# How to use javascript to detect flash is opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, flash

In my site, I injected a third party flash player using `iframe`, when user clicks a specific area in the flash player, the browser would open a new tab. I want to trace the rate of it.

Yet I get stuck, there might be two possible options,

- Detect the click event happened in the specific area. Yet, I don't know the `id`, the coordinates could be varied from the screen.
- Detect the new tab open event. But, firstly, how can I detect that my page is opending a new Tab? Further, how can I tell it is triggered by flash?

Could you please give me some advice?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript onclick event over flash object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try combining both of your suggested options. The coordinates would be varied, but you can very them dynamically by the iframe. Since the iframe is yours you can get its coordinates, unless what you mean is that the iframe could be scrolled or changed position within.

If you don't want to allow scripts at all (including the one that opens the tab, possibly) you could use the [sandbox attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) of an iframe.