# document.getElementById to include href

Tags: href, getelementbyid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("IDOFELEMENT");
</script>
```

What is the correct way to turn this into a link?

Can I write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("IDOFELEMENT").href("http://www.address.com");
</script>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

javascript:

```
// this changes the href value<br>
document.getElementById("IDOFELEMENT").href = "http://www.address.com";
```

and the html:

```
<a href="www.toBeChanged.com" id="IDOFELEMENT">To Website< /a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should specify what kind of element is **IDOFELEMENT**. But you can't convert it to a link by just adding a href attribute, it only works if **IDOFELEMENT**
is an hyperlink like `<a id="IDOFELEMENT">stuff</a>`

Simplest way is to add an **onclick** event to the element that changes the url to desired address:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var element = document.getElementById("IDOFELEMENT");
   element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://address.com\'');
</script>
```

Or if you wanna wrap it with a hyperlink:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var element = document.getElementById("IDOFELEMENT");
   var parent = element.parentNode; 
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = 'http://www.address.com';
   link.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true)); 
   parent.replaceChild(link, element);
</script>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: sorry, your are correct in that I should have specified.  The element is a `<object>` element that contains a flash `.swf` file.  I will try both methods and see which works.

Comment: I don't think it will work, look this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459/how-do-you-use-a-flash-object-as-a-link and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object

Comment: Yea I think you're right.  I posed the wrong question, so I'm debating whether I should remove this post or keep it because it does serve most other instances.... I certainly don't want to have everyone's effort go unnoticed...

Comment: keep it, it could help someone with the same doubt

Answer (score 2):

I came accross the issue - Javascript error: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null.
I discovered this was due to executing this code while the DOM is not ready.
window.onload solved the issue for me.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

   var element = document.getElementById("IDOFELEMENT");
   var parent = element.parentNode; 
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = 'http://www.google.com';
   link.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true)); 
   parent.replaceChild(link, element);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your element in an anchor tag as follows...

```
<a href="http://www.address.com">
    <div id="IDOFELEMENT">
    ... content ...
    </div>
</a>
```