# How to redirect the url twice with document.getElementById("ID").href?

Tags: javascript, href, getelementbyid

Good Evening, This question is an extension for [document.getElementById to include href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213405/document-getelementbyid-to-include-href) I currently have a next hyperlinks and the next hyperlinks is using a javascript to overwrite the url. The first time I click the next hyperlinks, it works but when the second times I clicked it, it goes to the url which in the a tag but not the javascript. How can I make the next hyperlinks goes to the url which is in the javascript everytime I click it?

```
<script> 

//..
   function nextHyperLinks() {

          document.getElementById("nextID").href = "www.google.com";
   }
</script>

<HTML>
   //..
   <a href="www.yahoo.com" id="nextID" onclick="nextHyperLinks();">next</a>
</HTML>
```

If any things not clear, please let me know. Need some hints and advised, thanks.^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function nextHyperLinks(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("nextID").href = "www.google.com"; // you probably don't need this if you will anyway navigate away from the page.
  window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_self');
}

var el= document.getElementsById('nextID');
el.addEventListener('click', nextHyperLinks);
```

and remove the inline `onclick="nextHyperLinks();"`

Comment: ya, it works in the pure html web site...
may I know why u use the preventDefault?
will it works the same way if java servlet involve?

Comment: @薛源少 the preventDefault is so the link in the a tag will not be followed.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/45WQq/

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="nextID" onclick="this.href = 'http://www.google.com'" target="_blank">next</a>
```

Comment: erm, this work but not match with my requirement...
I need the javascript value to be pass, sorry...