# Flash banner link not work in Chrome

Tags: html, flash

In Firefox all is ok, but in Ie and Chrome not works, click in banner but link not work:
here example:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7fwt/

Code:

```
<a href="google.lt" target="_blank" ">
<object>
<param name="movie" value="http://new.sa.lt/wp-content/uploads/bannernow.swf">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="http://new.sa.lt/wp-content/uploads/bannernow.swf"></embed>
</object>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's really designed to work that way, you are just getting lucky that some of the browsers are letting you :)

If you look at this question you'll see there's a couple of ways to do it:
[How do you use a flash object as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459/how-do-you-use-a-flash-object-as-a-link)

One is to make the Flash itself act as a link. The other is to add a javascript handler for the object. i.e. onClick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" or put that into a method.